# What could cause Groove music to constantly pause playback?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-950, groove

I use my phone a portable music player whilst walking back and forth from work. Having moved to a phone that comes with Windows 10 Mobile, I've found that playback will pause for no apparent reason. Sometimes it'll be a few seconds after I've locked the screen, sometimes it'll almost straight after starting playback.

The songs are stored on the phone's internal memory, so I doubt it's related to buffering problems, but what be causing this? Is it just a shockingly bad bug to be present in this initial release?

Comment: This behavior has been present for several builds on both my Icon and 950XL, so I'm going to say it's a bug that is, yes, shockingly bad. I'd suggest making sure Groove is up to date, but I'm pretty sure you'll have tried that :P

Comment: This is on a retail 950, with no pending app updates, so time to dig out an alternate app if that is the case...

Comment: Yeah that's probably a good idea. I just had it happen to me this morning. Also removed all songs from Now Playing.

Comment: For the record, build 10.0.10586.107 released recently (as a production release) does not resolve the issue

Comment: If the songs aren't DRM protected you might try Mus'box. I haven't used it much at all myself (most of my music comes from Groove and is DRM protected), so it may have issues that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Just restart the device, it might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been using a headset from a  different phone, changing to use regular stereo headphones resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured for me in a freshly installed phone.

The issue was that Groove wasn't allowed to run in the background! Simply always allow it in the background and it's work as it should.