# Can I connect an external microphone and record sound from it?

Tags: lumia, audio-recording

Can I connect an external microphone to my Lumia 640 and record sound from it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. In principle, there are three ways to connect an external microphone:

- The 3.5 mm audio jack. You'll need a microphone with a 3.5 mm TRRS connector, or a suitable adapter if the microphone has a different connector (e.g. XLR). Note that TRRS merely determines the *number* of contacts in the connector (4 - tip, ring, ring, sleeve); [different standards exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#TRRS_standards) for which signal is passed through which connector. According to [this AAWP article](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/17561_Jays_AB_headset_for_Windows_Ph.php), first-gen WP8 Lumia phones (e.g. 820, 920) use a universal connector that works with the two most common standards (OMTP and AHJ), presumably the same applies to more recent Lumias as well, such as your 640.
- Bluetooth. Microphones that support Bluetooth appear to be pretty rare and mostly designed for the video industry. You may also run into problems with connectivity and audio quality. I do not recommend this option unless you have requirements that a wired microphone will not satisfy.
- USB. Unfortunately this is not possible on your Lumia 640 because [older Lumia phones lack the capability to act as USB hosts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdsettings/lumia-640-xl/03d5c649-3328-43cb-8525-14896843647e?auth=1). However, the newer Lumia 950 and 950 XL do support USB OTG and [have been tested to work with external USB microphones](http://www.windowscentral.com/lumia-950-and-usb-otg).

For a lot more useful information, see [Audio Recording With a Smartphone](http://www.wildmountainechoes.com/equipment/audio-recording-with-a-smartphone/)

This [list of audio recording apps for Windows Phone](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/19210_Recording_sound-7_audio_captur.php) might also be useful.

Comment: that first point may explain http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12473/106 if ground/mic are the "wrong" way around on the headset I have